# Is 2D toric code dual to something?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, topological-order, anyons

I can understand 2D toric code as a quantum Z2 gauge theory defined on a lattice. Is this model dual to some simpler spin model?

A bit of motivation to clarify my intention:
I know 3D classical Ising model can be mapped to 3D classical Z2 gauge theory where we have plaquettes in the Hamiltonian. This made me wonder if 2D toric code is dual to quantum/classical 2D Ising model or some variant thereof.

Comment: You need to specify what you mean by dual here.